# Sardine library not working with nextcloud docker compose behind nginx (SSL)

Tags: java, docker, webdav, nextcloud, sardine

i have a 3rd party application that uses sardine library to upload files.

i upgraded my nextcloud docker version to the latest one , and added SSL security (HTTPS)
also tested the webdav URL with Rclone , and i was able to upload and download files using rclone.

the issue now is only with sardine , at first i was able to download (import) files and that feature is still works as expected. but for upload (export) to nextcloud , i still have an issue.

in my sardine code , i am using sardine PUT (URL , inputsream ).
after attempting to upload , i am getting the error : “Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity”

thanks for the support, unfurentrly i cannot share the application logs because it uses some work related stuff which are private.